# Subtracting vector from vector and np.roll the result in Python

Tags: python, vector, subtraction

I have a vector of susceptible areas and a vector of newly infected areas for every year in my model. The rows indicate different population ages and the columns represent different years. I am trying to "age" the susceptible vectors by using np.roll. In the case of an epidemic, I need to subtract the newly-infected-area-vector and "age" the remainder. In earlier drafts, this was not a problem, however, for some reason it does not work anymore and results in

```
__main__:172: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

A small illustration of what I am trying to do is below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

years = range(10) 
# Vector1 illustrates the susceptible individuals (n) indicates the different ages
vector1 = [100 for n in range(100)]  
# Vector2 illustrates the newly infected individuals across ages. This constant should be subtracted for every year from the remainder at t-1.
vector2 = [10 for n in range(100)] 
# In this df, I would like to store the remainder of susceptible individuals. Rows indicate the possible ages (n), columns the point in time (t).
df = pd.DataFrame([[0 for t in years] for n in range(100)])

for n in range(100):
    for t in years:
        # In the first year, no infection occurs and the column is just the vector of susceptible individuals
        if t == 0:
            df[n] = vector1 
        # In t+1 the epidemic starts and for every year I want to subtract the newly infected individuals (vector2) from the vector of susceptible (and not yet infected) individuals which I have calculated at t-1
        elif t-1 >= 0:
            df[t][n] = np.roll(np.subtract(df[t-1][n], vector2[n]), shift=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it is working on my machine. However this is a kind of warning that you are getting. It won't stop your program.

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

This is a nice read for this warning